# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity / Seaborn and Matplotlib library

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is a runnable snippet of code which generates the error on my machine. I have this error (ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
from pandas import DataFrame



data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\yavuz\Desktop\Pokemon.csv", sep='\t', 
engine='python')

f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(18,18))

sns.heatmap(data.corr())

**Error**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yavuz/.PyCharmEdu2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 14, in <module>
    sns.heatmap(data.corr())
  File "C:\Users\yavuz\PycharmProjects\deneme\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 517, in heatmap
    yticklabels, mask)
  File "C:\Users\yavuz\PycharmProjects\deneme\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 167, in __init__
    cmap, center, robust)
  File "C:\Users\yavuz\PycharmProjects\deneme\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 206, in _determine_cmap_params
    vmin = np.percentile(calc_data, 2) if robust else calc_data.min()
  File "C:\Users\yavuz\PycharmProjects\deneme\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 32, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Process finished with exit code 1
```

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity pls help me

Comment: The best help you can expect here is a pointer to [mcve], as people usually have no magic power to know what `Pokemon.csv` is and what it contains.